# Bootstrap dropdown "across" divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu that I want to place to the right of a div, like so:
[image] (The dashed line is the edge of the next div.)

When I open the list, it gets filled to the width and then wraps to the next line:

[image]

Would it be possible to make the edge of the list go "across" the border into the next div without affecting it?

Current CSS

```
/* enclosing div */
#section-left {
    padding: 1em;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-right: 3px dashed #aaa;
}

/* the div to the right in the screenshots */
#section-middle {
    left: 25%;
    width: 45%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* where the dropdown and image are held */
#section-left-right {
    float: right;
    height: 120px;
}

#lessons-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
}

#lessons-progress-list li {
    padding: 0 1em;
}


#knacke-small {
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section-left" class="column">

        <div id="section-left-right">
            <div class="dropdown" id="lessons-dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">&#9776; Lektionslista</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="lessons-progress-list" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"> 
                        <!-- populated dynamically with <li>s -->
              </ul>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <img src=... id="knacke-small">
        </div>
             ...
 </div>

 <div id="section-middle">...
```

Answer (score 0):

your container `section-left` has `overflow`, it doesn't allow the inner divs to display outside the limits. I don't know the rest of the code. Do you really need it?

[check it without the overflow](http://codepen.io/Turqueso/pen/KoJGx)

Comment: I don't know what happened, when I looked at your code the first time, it seemed to be working but now it doesn't display the section-middle div. 
Unfortunately the project was finished three months ago so I don't have local access to the code anymore. Thanks for trying though.